# python network traffic monitor

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming

I am trying to write a code which can monitor network traffic, Is there a way I can to write the code which can monitor traffic (bandwidth) going in or out  and be able to see realtime bandwidth usage in python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you using Linux:

Read `/sys/class/net/{INTERFACE_NAME}/statistics/tx_bytes` & `/sys/class/net/{INTERFACE_NAME}/statistics/rx_bytes` to get the sended & received bytes. Then you can calculate the the difference between a time step and voila: you have the data rate.
For a description of tx/rx files see the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net-statistics).

Edit:
Quick & *dirty* implementation just to show the idea:

```py
import time

def transmissionrate(dev, direction, timestep):
    """Return the transmisson rate of a interface under linux
    dev: devicename
    direction: rx (received) or tx (sended)
    timestep: time to measure in seconds
    """
    path = "/sys/class/net/{}/statistics/{}_bytes".format(dev, direction)
    f = open(path, "r")
    bytes_before = int(f.read())
    f.close()
    time.sleep(timestep)
    f = open(path, "r")
    bytes_after = int(f.read())
    f.close()
    return (bytes_after-bytes_before)/timestep

devname = "wlo1"
timestep = 2 # Seconds
print(transmissionrate(devname, "rx", timestep))
```

Comment: I have an error since am new to python i have no idea what is the problem and yes am using.                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monitor.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(transmissionrate(devname, "rx", timestep))
  File "monitor.py", line 10, in transmissionrate
    f = open(path, "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/net/wlo1/statistics/rx_bytes'

Comment: Then you either doesn't use linux or your devicename isn't `wlo1`. To get the device names type `ip link` in a terminal.

Comment: Thank you very much senden9 it is now working, you are right it was the device name, youre good. I have another question is it possible to see the data usage (traffic) in real time. if numbers are changing I should be able to see them going up or down?

Comment: @Wylie: If it works for you please consider to upvote and/or mark the answer as correct. The number is exactly the number sended/received bytes. I have linked the documentation above.